# How to bundle all js files using closure-compiler

Tags: javascript, directory, bundle, wildcard, google-closure-compiler

I am trying to bundle all .js files in a specific folder, but receive a ': no such file or directory' error.

Here is my code:

```js
const ClosureCompiler = require('google-closure-compiler').jsCompiler;
const { writeFile } = require('fs');

const closureCompiler = new ClosureCompiler({
    js: 'c:/polyfill/**.js',
    js_output_file: 'bundle.js'
});

const compilerProcess = closureCompiler.run([{
    path: './',
}], (exitCode, stdOut, stdErr) => {
     writeFile(stdOut[0].path, stdOut[0].src,()=>{});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seem this path `js: 'c:/di/webapp/public/js/polyfill/**.js',` is wrong.If it is windows then normally after `c:/` you will get the `Users` directory.

You can go to the file location and right click on that to get the 'Properties' . Copy `Location` value and replace the backward slash with forward